# Swing JFrame setSize() actual size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

When I set the size of a JFrame it sets the total size of the window, including some borders.
But I need to place the components (buttons, tables, etc,...) corresponding to the actual size - the size of the space where it is possible to locate the components.

I know I can get the actual size by this function:

```
frame.getContentPane().getSize();
```

The problem is I need to hard-code the bounds for my components, so I was wondering if I set the size to (x,y) what is the actual size?

it seems like it might be (x-30,y-30), but will be very helpful to know exactly how much space I have when placing components with hard-coded bounds.

Since Swing is platform-independent, maybe the actual size varies between platforms/OSes? This is also a must to know when developing cross-platform GUIs in Swing.

Comment: You should avoid using setSize, setBounds or any other code that tries to force size and position in an absolute way, since this can create rigid GUI's that only work well on one operating system/platform and that are very hard to update and debug. Much better to use layout managers and `pack()` to allow components to size themselves in the best way.

Comment: Using `setSize()` on a top level frame is OK, but you should definitely *flee* from trying to use `setBounds()` on components.  Call `pack()` or use `revalidate()` if they are custom components that don't signal for revalidation on their own.  Use a layout manager.

Comment: Is it safe to say using setBounds(), setSize() for components is a bad practice when developing a cross-platform GUI in Swing? I am asking this because I do see many tutorials using these methods for some reason. Maybe just for code simplicity, but they set example for how to place components e.g, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-swing-jtable/#:~:text=Last%20Updated%3A%2018%2D06%2D,data%20in%20a%20tabular%20form.

Comment: The tutorial you should be using for Swing basics is the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). The section on Using Layout Managers will get your started.

Comment: *"..using setBounds(), setSize() for components is a bad practice"* **Yes!** *"I do see many tutorials using these methods"* Apparently many tutorials are made by people who have never had to see their GUIs on another OS, PLAF, screen size (etc.). Use the tutorial linked by @camickr

Comment: General tips: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.